# Replacing characters in a string - php

Tags: php, replace

I have a date variable and want to replace all the `/` with `-`. I can't figure out why this keeps returning the actual length of the string date. Is it a problem with the action line within my if statement?

```
<?php

$date = "20/12/2012";
$datenew = "";

for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($date); $i++) {

  if (($date{$i}) != "/") {

    $datenew += $date{$i};          

    }else{

    $datenew += "-"; 
   }

}

echo $datenew;

?>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Obviously you're not using [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: `+=` is for __adding__ values, `.=` __concatenates__ them

Comment: You mean this `echo str_replace('/','-',$date);` ?

Comment: What is `$date{$i}`. Shouldn't that be `$date[$i]`?

Comment: If you really have to do it using this convoluted method, then `for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($date); $i++){ if(($date{$i}) != "/"){ $datenew .= $date{$i}; }else{ $datenew .= "-"; }
}
`

Comment: Not +=, in php concatenation .=

Comment: @Barmar PHP (5.5) supports both, but subscripting with rectangle brackets is more common.

Comment: @MarkBaker `$i <= strlen($date)` will always generate a notice. String indexes start at zero, it should be `$i < strlen($date)`. As strings are immutable, `strlen($date)` should be stored in a variable and that should be used instead: `for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($date); $i < $len; ++$i)`. Finally, [`strlen(…)`](http://php.net/strlen) should be replaced with [`mb_strlen(…)`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) and subscripting with [`mb_substr(…)`](http://php.net/mb_substr) if available. That said, there are more efficient approaches to begin with :)

Comment: @PointedEars - I'll cede the point about `<=`, and it certainly should be stored in a variable.... but OP is using a stupidly convoluted method anyway; and what's the point of using mb_strlen() when you know that the data doesn't contain any multibyte characters

Comment: @MarkBaker *Iff* you know that the string does not contain any multibyte characters, then there is no point in using any of the multibyte string functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `+=` and

```
$date{$i}
```

You need `.=` and

```
$date[$i]
```

However the easiest is to use this:

```
$date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date="20/12/2012";
$newDate= implode("-",explode("/",$date));
echo $newDate; // outputs 20-12-2012
```